# [Unity, c#]. Video Player. Video flicker/blink on android just right before video starts

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, video-player

This is the first time I ask someone for help in this forum. Hope I'll get your help :)

Well, the issue is that, when scene loads, I start mp4 video with Unity's Video Player. I use Raw Image and RenderTexture with it. In editor and Bluestacks emulator everything is fine, but when I start the game on android, just right before the video starts - I get black screen for about ~1 second and then video starts normally. And every time it happens right before the video starts. Does anyone know how to fix this that video would start normally? I would greatly appreciate.

I am new with Video Player and don't understand what could be wrong. I assigned textures in my code.

[Image of component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWFFw.png)

```
void Start()
{
    renderTextureFirstVideo = new CustomRenderTexture(1080, 1920);
    renderTextureFirstVideo.initializationColor = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

    renderTextureLoopVideo = new CustomRenderTexture(1080, 1920);
    renderTextureLoopVideo.initializationColor = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

    time = _FirstVideo.clip.length;
    Timing.RunCoroutine(IShowVideo());
}

private IEnumerator<float> IShowVideo()
{
    yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(1f);
    _FirstVideoRawImage.texture = renderTextureFirstVideo;
    _FirstVideo.targetTexture = _FirstVideoRawImage.texture as RenderTexture;
    _FirstVideo.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    _FirstVideo.Play();

    yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds((float)time);

    _LoopVideoRawImage.texture = renderTextureLoopVideo;
    _LoopVideo.targetTexture = _LoopVideoRawImage.texture as RenderTexture;
    _LoopVideo.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    _LoopVideo.Play();
}
```

Comment: I would think `yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(1f);` always causes a wait of 1 second (but that would occur in the editor or an emulator too)

Comment: Solved. I made RawImage color (255f, 255f, 255f, 0f) for ~0.5f seconds to make it invisible in IEnumerator and then made it visible again. Now it looks good :))